# Вписать фотографию в ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

У меня есть ImageView  (квадрат), в него нужно вписать фотографию, таким образом, что бы если фотография сделана в вертикальной ориентации , то поля оставались слева и справа (рис.1), а если в горизонтальной ориентации, то снизу и сверху (рис.2). Как это можно сделать? Возможно есть какой-то специальный scaleType для этого?

Рисунок 1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рисунок 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), для Ваших целей необходимо использовать

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter" //В xml
```

Comment: Отлично работает с фотографиями, которые были сделаны в горизонтальной ориентации, а вот фотографии, которые были сделаны в вертикальной ориентации отображаются так же, как и те которые в горизонтальной (только с неправильным rotation), почему так происходит? Им нужно принудительно менять  rotation?

Comment: @Lucky_girl такое встречается иногда, что неправильная ориентация. Гляньте, к примеру, этот вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android